# LikeView on android not fully working

Tags: android, facebook

I have `likeview` on my `fragment`. when I click on it, it change to "other page" with `button` confirmation to like it. after I click ok its back to my original page but the `LikeView` text still "Like" not "Liked".

If i click it again, there is a note saying i already like it and asking if i want to unlike it.

> my code in my fragment content:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
likeView = (LikeView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.like_view_type1);

likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType(newsContentcontent.url, LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

> is there something i miss or wrong code?

also, what is the different between Like-view.Object Type.PAGE and `LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH? or just use LikeView.ObjectType.DEFAULT?`
the purpose is for like an article.

Comment: After Conformation page call notifyDataSetChanged in listview adapter.

Comment: it is not listview, i use simple fragment with simple layout contain WebView and LikeView